# How to call methods which type are return Module using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension, kodein

I have a two files `one.kt` and `two.kt`, i have innerclass in `one.kt` file. i want to call the that inner class when some action performed like button click in Two.kt file. I tried some of ways the innerclass is called but method does not call. please guide me what i had mistakes. The `One.kt` file call from `manifest` file. like this,

```
<application
        android:name="com.abc.cde.One"
```

**One.kt:**

```
open class One : MultiDexApplication(), KodeinAware {
    ---------------
    --------------
    OnCreate()
    ---------------
    ---------------

inner class CallmyClass() {

        fun CallMyMethod(i: Int) :Module {

            return Module {
                bind<ExchangeRateProvider>() with singleton { CryptoCompareExchangeProvider(this@One, instance()) }
                bind<SyncProgressProvider>() with singleton { SyncProgressProvider() }
                bind<WallethKeyStore>() with singleton { keyStore }
                bind<Settings>() with singleton { KotprefSettings }

                bind<CurrentTokenProvider>() with singleton { CurrentTokenProvider(instance()) }

                bind<AppDatabase>() with singleton { Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "maindb").build() }
                bind<NetworkDefinitionProvider>() with singleton { NetworkDefinitionProvider(instance()) }
                //bind<CurrentAddressProvider>() with singleton { InitializingCurrentAddressProvider(keyStore, instance(), instance(), applicationContext) }
                bind<CurrentAddressProvider>() with singleton { InitializingCurrentAddressProvider(keyStore, instance(), instance(), applicationContext,i) }

                bind<FourByteDirectory>() with singleton { FourByteDirectoryImpl(instance(), applicationContext) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Two.kt:**

```
class Two : AppCompatActivity(), KodeinAware {

    -----------
    -----------
    -----------

    oncreate()

    -------------
    --------------

     val dd = One().CallmyClass().CallMyMethod(1)
}
```

some blog say you can call this type of methods using this, but i dont know how to use in Activity class because it does not extend Application class.

```
    override val kodein = Kodein.lazy {
           import(CallMyMethod(1))
    }
```

i incluse this code in my One.kt file and i want to call from Two.kt file is it possible or not ? guie me please

> is it right ? to call like this val dd = One().CallmyClass().CallMyMethod(1). but it does not call my method because of  Above the method is  return Module type using KodeinAware.

Ref: https://proandroiddev.com/dependency-injection-with-kotlin-kodein-koin-3d783745e48d

**UPdate:**

```
private fun CallMyMethod(i: Int) :Module {
                return Module {

                    //bind<ExchangeRateProvider>() with singleton { CryptoCompareExchangeProvider(this@App, instance()) }
                    bind<ExchangeRateProvider>(overrides = true) with singleton { CryptoCompareExchangeProvider(this@App, instance()) }

                    //bind<SyncProgressProvider>() with singleton { SyncProgressProvider() }
                    bind<SyncProgressProvider>(overrides = true) with singleton { SyncProgressProvider() }

                    //bind<WallethKeyStore>() with singleton { keyStore }
                    bind<WallethKeyStore>(overrides = true) with singleton { keyStore }

                    //bind<Settings>() with singleton { KotprefSettings }
                    bind<Settings>(overrides = true) with singleton { KotprefSettings }

                    //bind<CurrentTokenProvider>() with singleton { CurrentTokenProvider(instance()) }
                    bind<CurrentTokenProvider>(overrides = true) with singleton { CurrentTokenProvider(instance()) }

                    //bind<AppDatabase>() with singleton { Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "maindb").build() }
                    bind<AppDatabase>(overrides = true) with singleton { Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "maindb").build() }

                    //bind<NetworkDefinitionProvider>() with singleton { NetworkDefinitionProvider(instance()) }
                    bind<NetworkDefinitionProvider>(overrides = true) with singleton { NetworkDefinitionProvider(instance()) }

                    //bind<CurrentAddressProvider>() with singleton { DuplicateInitializingCurrentAddressProvider(keyStore, instance(), instance(), applicationContext,1) }
                    bind<CurrentAddressProvider>(overrides = true) with singleton { DuplicateInitializingCurrentAddressProvider(keyStore, instance(), instance(), applicationContext,1) }

                    //bind<FourByteDirectory>() with singleton { FourByteDirectoryImpl(instance(), applicationContext) }
                    bind<FourByteDirectory>(overrides = true) with singleton { FourByteDirectoryImpl(instance(), applicationContext) }
                }
            }

            override val kodein = Kodein {
                //import(CallMyMethod(1), allowOverride = true)
                import(CallMyMethod(1))
            }
```

Comment: A Kodein Module is meant to be imported in a Kodein configuration.
What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: i want to , this, when my app runs initially some data are binding after that some action performed in activity i want Re-bind the some more data. so i try to call my  "CallMyMethod(i: Int) :Module" when button action in but it does not working proper way. i get this error "Binding bind<CurrentAddressProvider>() with ? { ? } must not override an existing binding." @SalomonBRYS

Comment: first time (bind<CurrentAddressProvider>() ) it will bind some data. and i want to rebind / overide the old data  with new one. so i tried like this "bind<ExchangeRateProvider>(overrides = true)" and "import(CallMyMethod(1), allowOverride = true)" but still app says  existing binding error @SalomonBRYS

Comment: You need to import the module with `allowOverride = true`.

Comment: i mension that line, see my comment

Comment: can you please read my update section in my question, i tried this ways but does not work @SalomonBRYS

Comment: Try `allowSilentOverride` : http://kodein.org/Kodein-DI/?5.2/core#_overriding

Comment: Try `allowSilentOverride` : http://kodein.org/Kodein-DI/?5.2/core#_overriding

Comment: i tried like this "val appDiModule = Kodein.Module(allowSilentOverride = true) {
            import(diModel)
        }" no success

Comment: and like this tooo "import(CallMyMethod(1), allowOverride = true)"

Comment: Here is mu updated question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52565281/how-to-rebind-the-module-at-secound-time-called-in-kodein