# How to Rebind the Module at secound time called in kodein?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependencies, kotlin-android-extensions, kodein

I have an `android` app, its developed in kotlin, also we use `kodein` dependence for binding the data.When the binding the data first time it will bind correctly but it does not bind at second time call.

```
inner class CallmyClass() : MultiDexApplication(), KodeinAware {

        val diModel = Kodein.Module {
            bind<ExchangeRateProvider>() with singleton { CryptoCompareExchangeProvider(this@App, instance()) }
            bind<SyncProgressProvider>() with singleton { SyncProgressProvider() }
            bind<WallethKeyStore>() with singleton { keyStore }
            bind<Settings>() with singleton { KotprefSettings }

            bind<CurrentTokenProvider>() with singleton { CurrentTokenProvider(instance()) }

            bind<AppDatabase>() with singleton { Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "maindb").build() }
            bind<NetworkDefinitionProvider>() with singleton { NetworkDefinitionProvider(instance()) }

            bind<CurrentAddressProvider>() with singleton { InitializingCurrentAddressProvider(keyStore, instance(), instance(), applicationContext,1) }

            bind<FourByteDirectory>() with singleton { FourByteDirectoryImpl(instance(), applicationContext) }

        }

        val appDiModule = Kodein.Module(allowSilentOverride = true) {
            import(diModel)
        }

        override val kodein: Kodein = Kodein {
            import(appDiModule)
        }
    }
```

the problemo is, when binding at first time 
this code will excute

```
bind<CurrentAddressProvider>() with singleton { InitializingCurrentAddressProvider(keyStore, instance(), instance(), applicationContext,i) }
```

and `"InitializingCurrentAddressProvider()"` this class called and executed successfully.

BUT 
 when i try to call these line

```
bind<CurrentAddressProvider>() with singleton { InitializingCurrentAddressProvider(keyStore, instance(), instance(), applicationContext,i) }
```

at second time the line is executed but

`"InitializingCurrentAddressProvider()"` this class does not execute. thats the problem, if the second the class is execute means 
 i will get the result then automatically result will bind. but it does not execute.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Why are you trying to rebind the same thing ?

Comment: e.g for 

initially ClassA run and bind the value is "some value"

aft that ClassB called and calculated some values and re-bind the NEW value like a 

"some value" to "Somthing New value".

Comment: did you got my point what i say???

Answer (score 0):

When you call kodein.instance() you get an instance of your binding and because your binding type is singleton: you get same instance as previous and just one time it will create, not any more, so InitializingCurrentAddressProvider(keyStore, instance(), instance(), applicationContext,i) just called once. switch singleton to provider to see calling InitializingCurrentAddressProvider(keyStore, instance(), instance(), applicationContext,i) every time you get instance(), InitializingCurrentAddressProvider(keyStore, instance(), instance(), applicationContext,i) executed.